# Macbook Pro 15" Mid-2015 with Windows 11: USB Ethernet slowness

Tags: macbook-pro, windows, bootcamp, usb, ethernet

Incorrect speed with USB to Gigabit Ethernet adapters in Macbook Pro 15" Mid-2015 with Windows 11:

Tried two adapters based on Realtek and Asix and the USB 3.0 ports, under Windows 11 do not go over 300 Mbps on a 1 Gbps internet connection.

On Mac, the same adapters and USB 3.0 ports deliver the expected speed (~900 Mbps).

How can I fix this issue in Windows 11?

Thank you